# Play Framework integration with Spark for data analytics with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, playframework, apache-kafka, analytics, spark-streaming

I have frontend which communicates with backend written on Play Framework, my target is to make analytics of users activity on this site like statistics of user activity in the certain time, actions by user gender, statistics of activity in different countries and etc. This data I would like to collect on the backend with `Play framework` and send it to `Kafka`, wherein `Spark streaming will ingest` this data make aggregation and write analytics to the database.

I have a doubt regarding next moment:

- Does Play framework can be the appropriate place for sending data to `Kafka` (e.g. via the separate controller with `Akka streams` or etc.) or I must use something else instead `Play` for this purpose?
- What is the best event to trigger the `producing to Kafka` on user activity - e.g. user made the certain action and immediately send data to Kafka or collect this data in memory and send when threshold will be limited.

p.s. Event with `Spark streaming` will be triggered every hour, `streaming` will consume data from `Kafka` and write it to the database. And I doubt that best solution will be simple consuming data as it arrives. If am wrong with this approach, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

*Event with Spark streaming will be triggered every hour, streaming will consume data from Kafka and write it to the database. And I doubt that best solution will be simple consuming data as it arrives. If am wrong with this approach, please correct me.*

[A] It depends on your business requirements. If you want near real-time insight then you would need to consume data as it arrives rather than in one-hour batch

*Does Play framework can be the appropriate place for sending data to Kafka (e.g. via the separate controller with Akka streams or etc.) or I must use something else instead Play for this purpose?*

[A] I would highly recommend using Kafka Streams in place of Spark given you are using Java. I dont know enough about the Play foramework to comment on it

*What is the best event to trigger the producing to Kafka on user activity - e.g. user made the certain action and immediately send data to Kafka or collect this data in memory and send when threshold will be limited.*

[A] In order to avoid affecting the application itself, sending messages to Kafka should be done in asynchronous manner